# MySQL when can I use HASH instead of BTREE

Tags: mysql, hash, indexing, innodb, b-tree

Since MySQL uses `BTREE` by default when creating an index, is there some instance when I can use `HASH`? For example, if my table only consists of Foreign Keys which are just `INT UNSIGNED` values. Is it a good improvement to override BTREE with HASH in this case?

Not sure if it matters, but I'm using `InnoDB`.

Comment: [Comparison of B-Tree and Hash Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/index-btree-hash.html).  Note that InnoDB does not support `HASH` indexes.

Comment: The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html) does a good job of explaining how each one works.

Answer (score 13):

The `HASH` index type is only supported for `MEMORY` (aka `HEAP`) storage engine.

Answer (score 1):

See here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_hash_index

> hash index
>
> A type of index intended for queries that use equality operators, rather than range operators such as greater-than or BETWEEN. `It is available for MEMORY tables`. Although hash indexes are the default for MEMORY tables for historic reasons, that storage engine also supports B-tree indexes, which are often a better choice for general-purpose queries.
>
> MySQL includes a variant of this index type, the adaptive hash index, that is constructed automatically for InnoDB tables if needed based on runtime conditions.