# InnoDB, how to detect the index types?

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE  `posts` (
  `post_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `forum_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `poster_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `icon_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `poster_ip` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_time` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_approved` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `post_reported` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `enable_bbcode` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `enable_smilies` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `enable_magic_url` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `enable_sig` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `post_username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_subject` blob,
  `post_text` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `post_checksum` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_attachment` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bbcode_bitfield` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `bbcode_uid` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_postcount` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `post_edit_time` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_edit_reason` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_edit_user` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_edit_count` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_edit_locked` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
  KEY `forum_id` (`forum_id`),
  KEY `topic_id` (`topic_id`),
  KEY `poster_ip` (`poster_ip`),
  KEY `poster_id` (`poster_id`),
  KEY `post_approved` (`post_approved`),
  KEY `post_username` (`post_username`),
  KEY `tid_post_time` (`topic_id`,`post_time`) USING HASH
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22381 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

as you can see, the last index is "USING HASH" - but when I use `show indexes from posts;`, thats not showing it

Answer (score 2):

After a quick [Google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418260/mysql-when-can-i-use-hash-instead-of-btree), I quickly found that [InnoDB doesn't support HASH indexes](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40710), but still accepts the modifier in table definitions.

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` may show USING HASH, but [`SHOW INDEXES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-index.html) will actually show you what index type is being used:

> `Index_type`
>
> The index method used (`BTREE`, `FULLTEXT`, `HASH`, `RTREE`).

Comment: this is the funniest part: show index WONT show that. I just marks "BTREE"